# Buildbot : how to manually launch a build?

Tags: c++, g++, buildbot

We are using BuildBot (http://buildbot.net/) to build our C++ project.
Is there any way to run the exact build commands from the command line that are executed when you hit the "force build" button on the web UI?  I'm trying to debug a build problem that is present on our build server but not on our local machines, and don't want to spam the email list each time it fails.

Thank you,
Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a command `COMMAND [ARG]...` in a clean environment use `env --ignore-environement COMMAND [ARG]...`.

Comment: OK so if I use the --ignore-environement flag then that would cause the system to not send an email on build failure?

Comment: No I don't suspect so. I suspect you can run the same build commands as BuildBot does in a similar environment. I did not intend for you to actually use BuildBot for this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume buildbot sends an http request to the buildbot server asking it to build when you hit the force build button.  So if you work out what it's senfing you can send the same thing using wget or python or whatever?

That may or may not do what you're trying to do?  I guess there's a difference between running buildbot builds from the cmd line and duplicating a buildbot build without using buildbot.